# Getting list of child OU in Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

Google Directory provide API to get all organizational units from domain. 
I'm able to get OU inside "/" but I want to get all child OU. 
There is function with some arguments:

```
 AdminDirectory.Orgunits.list(String costumerId, Object optionalArg)
```

This function accept "type" argument as mentioned in [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/orgunits/list), but when I put argument "orgUnitPath" it will respond with "Bad request"

Here is my full code

```
var page = AdminDirectory.Orgunits.list('my_costumer',{
  orgUnithPath: '/Kiosks',
  type: 'all'});
var units = page.organizationUnits;
if (units) {
  for (var i = 0; i < units.length; i++) {
    var unit = units[i];
    Logger.log(unit);
  }
} else {
  Logger.log('No units found.');
}
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mistyped 'my_customer' and orgUnitPath.  Also, organizationalUnits is going to be an array of objects that you will want to get specific properties of such as orgUnit.name, not log directly.

```
function listSubOUs() {
  var page = AdminDirectory.Orgunits.list('my_customer', {
      orgUnitPath: '/',
      type: 'all'
    });
    var orgUnits = page.organizationUnits;
    if (orgUnits) {
      for (var i = 0; i < orgUnits.length; i++) {
        var orgUnit = orgUnits[i];
        Logger.log('%s (%s)', orgUnit.name, orgUnit.orgUnitPath, orgUnit.description);
      }
    } else {
      Logger.log('No OUs found.');
    }
}
```